# Set input field value inside an external iframe using jquery or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am strongly facing iframe problem.I need to set value in other web side's input field.I post my code. already i am checking **contentDocument** (which return null) and **contentWindow** not work(which catch error) any one help me.

I was following link https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_frame_contentwindow.asp

But I am not success.When i check `console.log($('[name=name]'))` browser console detract,but use `console.log($('[name=name]').value=4)` then error.

When Browser console test use same code (`$('[name=name]').value=4`) ,sometime set the value,some time error.

Full code post for your testing

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
    iframe{
        border: none;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }
    </style>        
    <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <!-- <script  src="script/jquery-1.10.2.js?id=12"></script> -->
    <script>
        window.onload=function(){
            $("#btnLoad").on("click",function(){
                document.getElementById('ifUrl').src=$("#txtUrl").val();
                $("#btnFill").prop('disabled', true);
                document.getElementById("ifUrl").onload=function(){ 

                    setTimeout(function(){ $("#btnFill").prop('disabled', false); }, 5000)
                        $("#btnFill").on("click",function(){
                        var iframe = document.getElementById("ifUrl");
                        var innerDoc = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;
                        //var text = $("#ifUrl").contents(); 
                        console.log(innerDoc);
                        //console.log($('#ifUrl'))
                        });
                    };

                //alert($("#txtUrl").val());
                // $("#ifUrl").load(function() {
                //    alert()
                //     //alert($(this).contents().find("html"))
                // });

            });


        }


    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>URL: 
        <input type="text" id="txtUrl" value="https://www.dsebd.org/contact.php"/>
    </div>
    <div>
        <button id="btnLoad" type="button">Load Url</button>
        <button id="btnFill" type="button" disabled="true">Fill Up</button>
    </div>
    <div>
        <iframe id="ifUrl">

        </iframe>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: if you take a look to the console you can read "Blocked a frame with origin .... from accessing a cross-origin frame." Take a look to [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS)

Comment: thanks for your valuable link.I will read this.I will glad to u If u provide solution or reference link